# In the middle of writing answer on a question when it's closed and losing the answer content?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions

### Scenario

A moderator, review voters, etc. initiate a status change of a question to ***"closed"***, ***"off-topic"***, and so forth.  At the moment of the approved change someone was already in the middle of writing an answer *(even if the first and only)*, and their answer was not submitted before the question's status changed.

### Question

Does the answerer lose their work entirely or does the system prevent this sort of coincidence from occurring *(e.g. giving an error, enforcing a wait)*; whether at the side that decides to close it for example, or even if in a non-submitted and **"auto-saved"** or maybe **"not auto-saved"** state too?

### The Wondering Mind Thoughts

> I wonder if the "auto-save" configuration for answers being written
>   would make any difference in such an instance. For example, I wonder
>   if they were writing an answer before the time period of the first
>   auto-save, does that make any difference if the auto-save would have
>   already occurred.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As implied by [this MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188971/295684), if you're in the middle of composing an answer, you get a notification that the question has been closed and is no longer accepting answers. This disables the submit button (client-side only, as of that writing, not sure about now). You can copy out and save the text you've written, since the answering form is still there.

Comment: Good enough.... If it ever happens to me, I'll try to pay attention and post back and update for you to edit. This was just a thought I had at the time I asked the question so thanks for answering based on the detail you could find that others save posted about on Meta.